# Windows 7 shows Blue Screen with "STOP ntoskrnl 0x000001e" when accessing My Documents

Tags: windows-7, bsod

I have a Windows 7 PC that can boot, work normally and hibernate/restart all well, except whenever I open a file explorer and CLICK on "My Documents" , "Pictures", "Music" or "Videos" I get a BSOD:

> STOP ntoskrnl 0x000001e

Also if I navigate from C: to My Documents, upon entering My Documents, the same BSOD occurs.

Using BlueScreenView I found that `ntoskrnl.exe` is always in the stack's top 2, sometimes alone sometimes the first one will be something else: I've had dozens of this crash and it's pretty variable what the other driver is alongside ntoskrnl.

The very first crash was with the string "PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA" and since then they are all "KMODE_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED".

I can go into My Documents from a `cmd` window, and list files there. I ran `sfc /scannow` and it found no corruption. I have removed recently installed applications, and still this persists. chkdsk finds no corruption , and the bsod does not happen in safe mode.

This system is pretty generic, it had been hibernating on and off succesfully for months as I remember, I can't think of anything really big that changed recently (Firefox 13, Skype 5.9, Avast which I've now got rid of).

Any ideas would be much appreciated: My Documents is actually a place I like to visit often!

Comment: Official documentation for your STOP code: [Bug Check 0x1E: KMODE_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff557408(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Please see [Crash Dump Analysis](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee416349(v=vs.85).aspx) if you want to retrieve further information from the generated crash dump.

Comment: Thanks!I will run chkdsk and test memory just in case. However: the fact that it occurs at specific actions and not randomly makes me think it's not a physical problem with RAM? The fact that I can do dir in My Documents in the cmd window makes me think it's not a disk problem?

Comment: I am inclined to believe there is some corruption the hard drive (more specifically MFT) since it only happens with some directories. If chkdsk does not work see if you can open the folder from a different computer (though still win-7)

Comment: @imateapot: The most promising results are always obtained by loading the crash dump into a debugger like WinDBG. It allows you to analyze the dump and gain further insight into what may have caused the issue.

Comment: I had a similar issue when right clicking on any drive in my computer screen. It turned out to be a bad menu extension. In particular it was acronis trueimage free from western digital.

Comment: Thank Oliver Salzburg: I have succeeded in getting windbg running (accessing the minidump folder outside of safe mode also causes bsod!). So windbg says that it's ksecdd.sys causing the bsod. I'm discovering this tool: I typed !thread to get an idea of the calling process (apparently), and the result was "GetPointerFromAddress: unable to read from" etc . Will spend more time on this and post as understanding progresses. Please advise if somehow you know it's a virus. Thanks!

Comment: Have you ran a complete AV scan and complete Anti-malware scan?

Comment: Nothing from microsoft security essentials, malwarebytes or ad-aware.. Btw, it doesn't happen in safe mode..still looking.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like it's a faulty HDD, following on from Oliver's comments above I would recommend running a full hard disk diagnostic ([Hiren's Boot CD](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CFYQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.hiren.info%2Fpages%2Fbootcd&ei=kxXfT8_0Ma-U0QWn46HHDA&usg=AFQjCNFDGlsjyuXmhWBu02AqzEvCkj8D_Q) is good for this).

Once you are sure your HDD is healthy next check would be a RAM test (because it's quick, easy and worth doing - use memtest, also on Hirens).

As you've run SFC then the filesystem should be intact, but (as also mentioned by Oliver) a full chkdsk will check this for you (like a memory test, it's worth doing for peace of mind).

After all these tests are done, if the problem persists the next stages would be a complete low level format and reinstall of Windows, quite obviously a last resort!

Comment: Sounds like a Virii or Root Kit to me

Comment: Could be, but why would it only occur when entering any Win7 library and nothing else odd happening?

Comment: Because of the rootkit, by virtue of the same question how come he can access the convents via CMD?

Comment: Windows UI/API being unable to read additional file information/attempting to view corrupted info due to a faulty area of disk. Neither of us is correct (or incorrect) as both are valid and need further diagnostics! :)